# How do I format my data as a table with doubled line separators in my posts?

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

Can anyone tell me how to format a table like the below? I have copied the structure from this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520737/only-query-for-date-objects-in-oracle-sql)

```
╔════╦══════╦════════════╦═════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║  BIRTHDAY  ║ AGE ║  DEATHDAY  ║
╠════╬══════╬════════════╬═════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ JIM  ║ 10/20/1942 ║  70 ║ 11/21/2012 ║
║  2 ║ BOB  ║ 01/11/1930 ║  60 ║ 02/11/1990 ║
╚════╩══════╩════════════╩═════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post | http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/is-there-a-webapp-to-create-ascii-art-tables

Comment: List of unicode box-drawing characters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

Comment: @Deduplicator - That's exactly what i was looking for :). But am finding difficult to use it in here. Can you help me with it

Comment: You know, if you go for ASCII (and a slightly less refined look) things get easier: Just use `+-|`, like shown here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/8232 Or look at @Pang's links to find something for automating it.

Comment: As someone who answers a lot of SQL questions, I actually recommend you don't format it this way. Just use plain whitespace and highlight it as a code block to preserve all the space. Doing so makes it a lot easier for us to grab your table and import it to a database utility or sqlfiddle so that we can prototype an answer quickly. All the extra formatting just gets in the way, and does not improve readability appreciably over whitespace.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I thought this looked really neat, until you pointed out the function versus form trade-off. ;-)

Comment: Fact is it looks neat and good..  I just want to post my result in answer like this format 

Comment: This also looks awful when you see it in searches.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Those lines are [Unicode box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character).  You can easily make such "text art" tables yourself just by copy-pasting the characters from an existing table, or e.g. from the linked Wikipedia page.

```
  ╔══════╗
  ║ See? ║         ╔══════╗
  ╚══════╬═════════╣ Yay! ║
         ║ This is ╠══════╝
         ║ easy!   ║
         ╚═════════╝
```

Or, easier yet, use e.g. one of these automated online text table generators (found with a quick Google search):

- [Senseful Solutions: Format Text as a Table](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/) and its fork [Ascii Tables](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)
- [Text Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables)
- [MySQL table to text / HTML converter](http://scriptun.com/mysql/table-to-text-converter) (should work for other databases too)

For more general box / line art, you could also use an ASCII / Unicode line drawing app like [ASCIIFlow](http://asciiflow.com/).

Comment: Which is something i want to avoid :)

Comment: You can use http://asciiflow.com/ but it uses `+`,`-` and `|` instead of those fancy line thingers.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Actually, ASCIIFlow seems to have an option to use Unicode line drawing characters: just click the question mark on the top right and select "Lines Mode". Anyway, I just added a bunch of links to online text table generators.

Comment: Those were the days... autoexec.bat, config.sys and Pascal comments while those nights to increase EMS while formatting comments with these beautiful symbols. ;-). I wish to all of you  good new year.

Comment: Thats right. But not a Unicode, its just an ASCII symbols. People used it to draw interfaces long long ago :)

Comment: @Alex: Technically, those characters originally came from [IBM code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), which got borged up into Unicode along with just about every other old character set.

Answer (score 12):

If all you want is an ASCII table with the result of a MySQL query you can use the `-t` command line argument for this. Do note however that the ASCII characters used are different from your linked question:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Bob   |
|  2 | Alice |
+----+-------+
```

which would be generated by something along the lines of

```
mysql -t "select * from users"
```

Answer (score 5):

Some characters for reference:

```
╔    ╗    ╚    ╝    ═    ║    ╠    ╣    ╦    ╩    ╬
```

Box:

```
╔════╗
║    ║
╚════╝
```

Table:

```
╔════╦════╦════╦════╗
║    ║    ║    ║    ║
╠════╬════╬════╬════╣
║    ║    ║    ║    ║
╠════╬════╬════╬════╣
║    ║    ║    ║    ║
╠════╬════╬════╬════╣
║    ║    ║    ║    ║
╚════╩════╩════╩════╝
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the complete set of single/double line combinations for quick reference.

```
┌──┬┐  ╒══╤╕  ╓──╥╖  ╔══╦╗
│  ││  │  ││  ║  ║║  ║  ║║
├──┼┤  ╞══╪╡  ╟──╫╢  ╠══╬╣
└──┴┘  ╘══╧╛  ╙──╨╜  ╚══╩╝
```

Comment: Related: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23743/smallest-unicode-box-drawing