# How do I make a CSV suitable for display on SO?

Tags: discussion, support

I've been researching a detail within the Apple iOS SDK and created a 30 row matrix of attribute/entitlement pairs.

I want to paste this consolidation neatly into an SO question, since it adds context and value to my question.

What is the right way to take this matrix, and paste this into a question?

Failed attempts include

- Paste as CSV into code view (ugly)
- Replace commas with 5 spaces (font issue? No alignment)
- Add a photo (no SEO benefit)

I'm on OS X but have a Windows VM. Ideas appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Isn't "just don't post the entire csv" an option?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/ but what Braiam says should really be the norm. Is every one of those 30 lines really relevant to the question?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313648/2675154

Comment: Will people need to parse it to come up with a solution?